# How to put text after a \figure on a new page in case of several figures?

Tags: floats, page-breaking

I have a chapter which has 10-ish pairs of code example+figure. I wish to display the code examples on a new page (not on the same page as the previous figure), while the figure remains on top of the page.

I tried it with `\newpage` which does nothing, and `\clearpage` which works only the first time, after that it puts the figures in the middle of the page, which is not what I want.

How can I do this?

PS: I use `\lstinputlisting` and `\begin{figure}[th]`.

Comment: Its due to the h optional parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I force the picture to be at top with `[t!]`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.txt}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis.
Curabitur dictum gravida mauris.
Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget,
consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna.
\end{filecontents}

\newcommand{\essai}{\clearpage%
    \begin{figure}[t!]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=.4\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \end{figure}
    
    \lstinputlisting{\jobname.txt}
}

\begin{document}
    Some text
    \essai
    To try if \verb|\clearpage| works
    \essai
    \essai
\end{document}
```

### Edit

Just switch the order in the command:

```
\newcommand{\essai}{%
    \lstinputlisting{\jobname.txt}
    \begin{figure}[ht]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=.4\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \end{figure}
    \clearpage
}
```

Comment: I probably didn't formulate clear enough, sorry. It's the other way around. Text first, image (wherever it lands, preferably on top) then the next text should be on a new page.

Comment: @topkek see the edit. If needed, remove the `clearpage` in the command and add it manually.